# creating continuous spline curve in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, spline

I am trying to implement a spline curve like on [this image](http://schepers.cc/svg/path/spline.svg) with the green control at the side of each node and after finishing make the ends join each other.

Now the only way I found is to implement a polyline with joint points,  calculate the points of catmull curve after getting three joints, then connect theses points and plot them using the polyline and update the catmull points after moving any of joint points. But I found this procedure computationally intensive, so is there any way that fast mimics the spline in the link and also with green controls?

Thanks in advance.

```
private List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
private static ArrayList<Double> vx = new ArrayList<>();
public static boolean strtdrag;
public static double difx,dify;
static int ind;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group group = new Group();
    Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(0,0,400,400);
    rec.setFill(Color.BISQUE);
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
    polyline.setSmooth(true);
    group.getChildren().addAll(rec,polyline);
    group.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
        if (event.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        Circle df = joint(event.getX(),event.getY(),polyline);
        group.getChildren().add(df);
        double[]z= {event.getX(),event.getY()};
        polyline.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {event.getX(),event.getY()});
        x.add(z);
        vx.add(event.getX());
        vx.add(event.getY());
        }
    });
    // create scene which can be dragged and zoomed
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
private static Circle joint(double x ,double y,Polyline polyline ) {
    Circle df = new Circle(x,y,5);
    df.setFill(Color.RED);
    df.setOnMousePressed(event->{
        strtdrag=true;
        for(int i = 0; i < vx.size(); i+=2) {
            if (vx.get(i)==df.getCenterX()) {
                ind=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        difx=event.getX();
        dify=event.getY();
    });

    df.setOnMouseDragged(event->{
        if(strtdrag) {
            double diffx=event.getX()-difx;
            double diffy=event.getY()-dify;
            difx=event.getX();
            dify=event.getY();
            df.setCenterX(df.getCenterX()+diffx);
            df.setCenterY(df.getCenterY()+diffy);
            vx.set(ind, df.getCenterX());
            vx.set(ind+1, df.getCenterY());
            polyline.getPoints().remove(0, vx.size());
            polyline.getPoints().addAll(vx);
        }   
    });
    df.setOnMouseReleased(event ->{
        strtdrag=false;
    });
    return df;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [CubicCurve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurve.html) class which represents a cubic [Bézier parametric curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) segment and has control points.

I've written an example that allows you to create something like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplineCurve extends Application {

    private List<Anchor> points = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500,500, Color.BISQUE);
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                double x = event.getX(), y = event.getY();
                if (!points.isEmpty()) {
                    Anchor start = points.get(points.size() - 1);
                    CubicCurve curve = createCurve(start, x, y, group);
                    Anchor end = new Anchor(Color.TOMATO, curve.endXProperty(), curve.endYProperty(), 5);
                    group.getChildren().add(end);
                    points.add(end);
                } else {
                    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(Color.TOMATO, x, y, 5);
                    anchor.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            Anchor start = points.get(points.size() - 1);
                            CubicCurve curve = createCurve(start, anchor.getCenterX(), anchor.getCenterY(), group);
                            curve.endXProperty().bind(anchor.centerXProperty());
                            curve.endYProperty().bind(anchor.centerYProperty());
                            points.clear();
                            e.consume();
                        }
                    });
                    group.getChildren().add(anchor);
                    points.add(anchor);
                }
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private CubicCurve createCurve(Anchor from, double x2, double y2, Group group) {
        double x1 = from.getCenterX(), y1 = from.getCenterY();
        double distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
        CubicCurve curve = new CubicCurve();
        curve.setStartX(x1);
        curve.setStartY(y1);
        curve.setControlX1(x1 + 20 * (x2 - x1) / distance);
        curve.setControlY1(y1 + 20 * (y2 - y1) / distance);
        curve.setControlX2(x2 - 20 * (x2 - x1) / distance);
        curve.setControlY2(y2 - 20 * (y2 - y1) / distance);
        curve.setEndX(x2);
        curve.setEndY(y2);
        curve.setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
        curve.setStrokeWidth(4);
        curve.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        curve.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        curve.startXProperty().bind(from.centerXProperty());
        curve.startYProperty().bind(from.centerYProperty());
        Line controlLine1 = new ControlLine(curve.controlX1Property(), curve.controlY1Property(), curve.startXProperty(), curve.startYProperty());
        Line controlLine2 = new ControlLine(curve.controlX2Property(), curve.controlY2Property(), curve.endXProperty(), curve.endYProperty());
        Anchor control1 = new Anchor(Color.FORESTGREEN, curve.controlX1Property(), curve.controlY1Property(), 3);
        Anchor control2 = new Anchor(Color.FORESTGREEN, curve.controlX2Property(), curve.controlY2Property(), 3);
        group.getChildren().addAll(curve, control1, control2, controlLine1, controlLine2);
        return curve;
    }

    class ControlLine extends Line {
        ControlLine(DoubleProperty startX, DoubleProperty startY, DoubleProperty endX, DoubleProperty endY) {
            startXProperty().bind(startX);
            startYProperty().bind(startY);
            endXProperty().bind(endX);
            endYProperty().bind(endY);
            setStrokeWidth(2);
            setStroke(Color.FORESTGREEN.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
        }
    }

    // a draggable anchor displayed around a point.
    class Anchor extends Circle {
        Anchor(Color color, DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y, double radius) {
            super(x.get(), y.get(), radius);
            setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
            setStroke(color);
            setStrokeWidth(2);
            setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            x.bind(centerXProperty());
            y.bind(centerYProperty());
            enableDrag();
        }
        Anchor(Color color, double x, double y, double radius) {
            super(x, y, radius);
            setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
            setStroke(color);
            setStrokeWidth(2);
            setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            enableDrag();
        }
        // make a node movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
        private void enableDrag() {
            final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
            setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
                // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
                dragDelta.x = getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
                dragDelta.y = getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
                getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            });
            setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND));
            setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
                double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
                if (newX > 0 && newX < getScene().getWidth()) {
                    setCenterX(newX);
                }
                double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
                if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
                    setCenterY(newY);
                }
            });
            setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
                if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                }
            });
            setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
                if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                }
            });
        }
        // records relative x and y co-ordinates.
        private class Delta { double x, y; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much that is exactly what i wanted but is there any way to convert the result shape into a polygon i have modified the code a little bit to close the curve when done so i can convert it into a polygon but i can't keep the same shape @Kirill Simonov

Comment: @AhmedElshorbagy check my update, I've added an ability to close the curve